# create customized dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Have a dictionary something like this

```
{'A': [0.06, 0.1], 'B': [10.69, 13.58]}
```

wanted to convert to list of dictionaries

```
list = [
  {"name": A, "data": [0.06, 0.1]},
  {"name": B, "data": [10.69, 13.58]}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
md = {'A': [0.06, 0.1], 'B': [10.69, 13.58]}
nd = [{'name': x,'data': md[x]} for x in md]
print(nd)
```

Here `nd` is your output dict.

Output from IPython shell:

```
In [7]: md = {'A': [0.06, 0.1], 'B': [10.69, 13.58]}
   ...: nd = [{'name': x,'data': md[x]} for x in md]
   ...: print(nd)
[{'name': 'A', 'data': [0.06, 0.1]}, {'name': 'B', 'data': [10.69, 13.58]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `dict.items` for this:

```
D = {'A': [0.06, 0.1], 'B': [10.69, 13.58]}

L = [{"name" : k, "data" : v} for k, v in D.items()]

print(L)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'data': [0.06, 0.1]}, {'name': 'B', 'data': [10.69, 13.58]}]
```